# format current time to yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00

Tags: sql-server

By using the below query i get the first day of month of current date

```
  SELECT  DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(getdate())-1),getdate())
```

result: 2014-04-01 15:41:06.257

I need change hour, minus, second in 00:00:00 format, I Want something like

2014-04-01 00:00:00

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns a `datetime` value — the count of milliseconds since the SQL Server clock's *epoch* of 1 Jan 1900 00:00:00.000.

A `datetime` value has only the textual representation you give it (and if you don't explicity specify it, you'll get the default configured for your SQL Server).

You can do any of the following:

- Convert it to a `date` value (assuming a recent-ish version of SQL Server):

  ```
  select convert(date,
           dateadd(day,
             1-day(current_timestamp) ,
             current_timestamp
             )
           )
  ```
- You can strip the time component by doing a little date/time arithmetic:

  ```
  select dateadd(day,
           datediff(day,
             '', -- 1 Jan 1900 00:00:00.000
             current_timestamp
             ) - day(current_timestamp) + 1,
             '', -- 1 Jan 1900 00:00:00.000
           )
  ```
- Since a `datetime` value is a pair of 32-bit signed integers, you can manipulate its internal representation to chuck the time component:

  ```
  select convert(datetime,
           substring(
             convert(varbinary(8),current_timestamp),
             1,
             4
             ) + 0x00000000
           )
  ```

If what you actually want is a textual representation of the date for display, you can simply convert to to the desired form:

```
select convert(char(10),
         dateadd(day,
           1-day(current_timestamp) ,
           current_timestamp
           ),
         120
         )
```

Answer (score 4):

This will get there, too:

`select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)`